# Cleaning up comma & spaces after replace

Tags: javascript

Assume there are three fruit names in a string, which can be in any order. For example

```
var frt = "banana, apple, orange";
var frt = "apple, banana, orange";
var frt = "banana, orange, apple";
```

Now, I remove one (randomly) fruit using this:

```
var frt_rem = "apple";
frt = frt.replace(frt_rem, "");
```

This will leave the orginal string as follows:

```
var frt = "banana, apple, orange"; // banana, , orange
var frt = "apple, banana, orange"; // , banana, orange
var frt = "banana, orange, apple"; // banana, orange,
```

The comma and white spaces are unpredictably left in the string. Is there a good way to cleanup the string?

Comment: Use `split()` and `join()` ?

Comment: Maybe this `"banana, apple, orange".split(', ').filter(fruit => fruit !== 'apple').join(', ');`

Comment: wouldn't it be useful to use an array instead of a string considering this problem?

Comment: @HassanImam Your suggestion worked the best. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a reusable function that will split the string using comma and then remove that fruit from the array. After that, join the array elements with comma and a whitespace, something like below:

```js
function removeFruits(str, removeWord){
  var strArray = str.split(',').map(x=>x.trim());
  strArray.splice(strArray.indexOf(removeWord), 1);
  var res = strArray.join(', ');
  return res;
}
var frt = "banana, apple, orange";
var frt_rem = "apple";
var res = removeFruits(frt, frt_rem);
console.log(res);
frt = "apple, banana, orange";
res = removeFruits(frt, frt_rem);
console.log(res);
frt = "banana, orange, apple";
res = removeFruits(frt, frt_rem);
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Before replace added comma in replace function Like...

```
var frt_rem = "apple";
frt = frt.replace(", " + frt_rem, "");
```

Comment: This won't work when the string is var frt = "apple, banana, orange";

Answer (score 0):

Split the string into array, it makes easy to cleanup and replace element.

```js
var frt_rem = "apple";

function replaceArray(frt) {
  var splitArray = frt.replace(/ /g, "").split(",");
  var index = splitArray.indexOf("apple");
  if (index > -1) {
    splitArray.splice(index, 1);
  }
  return splitArray.join(", ");
}

var frt = "banana, apple, orange";
console.log(replaceArray(frt)); //banana, orange

frt = "apple, banana, orange";
console.log(replaceArray(frt)); //banana, orange

frt = "banana, orange, apple";
console.log(replaceArray(frt)); //banana, orange
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
frt.replace("apple","").replace(/\s/g, '').split(",").filter(String).join(",")
```